# Error with @google-cloud/storage using generateSignedPostPolicyV4

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm following this example:
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/generateV4SignedPolicy.js

My only changes were:

```
const bucketName = "gs://my-bucket.appspot.com/";
const filename = "test.jpg";

const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: require("./key.json").project_id,
  credentials: require("./key.json"),
});
```

Then I exported the output to a HTML file to test it:

```
node index.js > index.html
```

But when I submit the file, I receive:

```
<Error>
   <Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
   <Message>
      The content of the form does not meet the conditions specified in the policy document.
   </Message>
   <Details>
      Policy did not reference these fields: bucket submit
   </Details>
</Error>
```

Is it a bug on the code example?

Do I need any configuration/permissions on my part?

Comment: It can be possible that the `gs://` in the bucket name is not required, since it the on the example you share it states that `'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket'` try that out and let me know if it works.

Comment: @ralemos same issue =/

Comment: Are there any fields named `bucket submit`? The error message indicates that there is a field with that name/type, which is weird as it would have be either bucket or submit.

Comment: Same issue here, was working 30ish hours ago and suddenly stopped.

Comment: @ralemos Nice catch on the 'submit'. It named the submit button as `name='submit'`. But there is no bucket.

Comment: So did renaming the submit button fixed the issue?

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, what if you add bucket to the list of fields? 
```const options = {
      expires,
      fields: {
        'x-goog-meta-test': 'data',
        'bucket': 'bucket_name'
    },
};
```

Comment: @kozan can you check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74081978/error-creating-gcs-signed-post-policy-for-uploading-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this last working on Monday, May 11. I think they updated the API to not add the bucket to the list of fields automatically. Fix is simple, just add the bucket to the list of fields on creation.

```js
...
const options = {
  expires,
  fields: {
    'x-goog-meta-test': 'data',
    'bucket': 'my-bucket'
  },
};
...
```

Edit: Found the PR that references this breaking change. https://github.com/googleapis/conformance-tests/pull/31. [There will likely be an update to @google-cloud/storage module](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/pull/1168) sometime soon with the fix.