# Wordpress Google Storage Upload

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a Wordpress plugin and wanted to upload to my Google Cloud Storage bucket from a form.

I can do this quite easily using HTML forms here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-forms#html

However, when I try the PHP code snippet, I get a critical error. I used composer to install the Google StorageClient library with `composer require google/cloud-storage` .

When I try to use generateSignedPostPolicyV4 as the PHP example suggests, I get a critical error instead of uploading the file as with the HTML form. Could someone please let me know why using the PHP library generates an error?

Code below:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket('uploads');
$response = $bucket->generateSignedPostPolicyV4(
        'test-object',
        new \DateTime('10 min'),
        [
            'fields' => [
                'x-goog-meta-test' => 'data'
            ]
        ]
);
```

I've tested up to the $response variable, and everything works until that line.

Thanks in advance.

As with the HTML form example, the end result should be an uploaded file

Comment: What is the error and the stack trace? Update your question with debugging details.

Comment: @Lera What error you are getting?Also as mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61783141/18265638) try adding the bucket to the list of fields.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.